# SwiftUI View Extension is called on View load/refresh

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-view

We created a custom view extension to extend the functionality of `.alert` and add a bunch of customizations to fit with our needs;

```
import SwiftUI

extension View {
    
    public func alertX(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, content: () -> AlertX) -> some View {
        
        let alertX_view = AlertX_View(visible: isPresented, alertX: content())
        let alertXVC = AlertXViewController(alertX_view: alertX_view, isPresented: isPresented)
        alertXVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        alertXVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        alertXVC.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
        
        if isPresented.wrappedValue == true {
            if AlertX_View.currentAlertXVCReference == nil {
                AlertX_View.currentAlertXVCReference = alertXVC
            }
            
            let viewController = self.topViewController()
            viewController?.present(alertXVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            alertXVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        
        return self
    }
    ... truncated for brevity
}
```

It is called on a view in the same way as .alert is called;

```
        .alertX(isPresented: $viewModel.showAlert) {
            AlertX(logo: networkStore.currentNetwork.networkTheme.systemLogo ,
                   logoColor: networkStore.activeColors.lightTextColor ,
                   backgroundColor: networkStore.activeColors.primaryColor,
                   title: Text("AlertX Test"))
        }
```

Where `$viewModel.showAlert` is `@Published var showAlert: Bool` and `AlertX` is a custom view that contains our proprietary customizations to fit with our B2B application.

The issue I am having is that the information inside the closure for  `.alertX(isPresented:`  is called every time the view loads or changes state, regardless of whether or not the `$viewModel.showAlert` binding changes. The same is NOT true of the built in `.alert` view extension which is ONLY called when the `$viewModel.showAlert` value changes.

What modifications do I need to make in my implementation of `public func alertX(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, content: () -> AlertX) -> some View {` so that the information inside the closure it is only called when the binding value changes?

Comment: `alertX` *is* going to get called on each re-render no matter what. So is `alert`. Is the issue that the information *inside* the closure is getting called each time? Have you tried using `@autoclosure`?

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the post to be more specific about this

Comment: I see the edits, but I don't see whether you have tried to annotate it with `@autoclosure` (https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-the-autoclosure-attribute)

Comment: I tried it with @autoclosure, it did not make any difference

Comment: It is just a function - it will be *always* called.

Comment: Okay, I think I get the issue -- you basically need some way to see if the alert has already been presented, so that you don't evaluate the closure and try to present another view controller, right?

Comment: @jnpdx exactly, just like the built in .alert - the question is how :)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that SwiftUI will reload all of the structs and functions all the time - and then decides, based on the data dependencies, which part to redraw. So any code in your view functions will run. A lot.

Try this: at the top of that function, put

```
guard isPresented.wrappedValue == true else {
    return
}
```

Instead of checking it later on in the function.

Related, you might also want to look into making this code into a ViewModifier, and then your alertX function just applies the viewModifier based on the isPresented binding, otherwise returns self.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try the view modifier approach